# Devise multiple sign up pages Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to create different sign up pages for each event in my web app.

I'm using Devise, Cancan and Rolify.

Below is my signup form at the moment:

```
.container
  %h2
    Sign up
  .tab-content
    .tab-pane.active{:id => "signup"}
      = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-signin'}) do |f|
        = f.error_notification
        = f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, input_html: { class: "form-control"}, :placeholder => "Email"
        - if f.object.password_required?
          = f.input :password, :required => true, input_html: { class: "form-control"}, :placeholder => "Password"
          = f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true, input_html: { class: "form-control"}, :placeholder => "Password Confirm"
        = f.input :first_name, :required => true, :autofocus => true, input_html: { class: "form-control"}, :placeholder => "First name"
        = f.input :last_name, :required => true, :autofocus => true, input_html: { class: "form-control"}, :placeholder => "Last name"
        = f.button :submit, "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
  = render "devise/shared/links"
```

Is there a way we can add in fields from `events` table so those fields are populated with different urls so each one of them have dedicated signup page for visitors?

Comment: As a user, you would like me to sign up again for a different event? Can you please give an example of an event?

Comment: @andHapp event is a product name for a virtual conference app. I have events table, resources for supporting different events so I need to be able to support them by providing visitors to sign up automatically to the available events with dedicated url each

Comment: Any reason why you are not having them login into the site and then letting them select the event?  Why do you need them to login at the event level?